Elementor/HTML making Map fullscreen
I want to add a Google Maps to my Elementor Project and I did so by using the provided html code by Google. I wnat to show the Map fullscreen. The problem is, that the map is not showen in full height.
I made an section which is "fit so screen" and in this section I have a html element with the following code:
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?hereIsMyKey" width="640" min-height: 100vh></iframe>


The exact height of an iframe can be set using CSS.
Elementor Pro
In a Custom CSS field on the Advanced tab of an element:
selector iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

Elementor Free
A code can be placed directly in the HTML element:
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?hereIsMyKey" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></iframe>

